# How to access the coded layer complete matrix z in training autoencoder using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

Basically, I need to grap the values of code z as a complete matrix. For example, I have 60,000 MNIST Images with dimension 28 X 28 and code layer dimension is 32.

So, I'm expected my output to be 60,000 X 32 instead of 60,000 X 784.

I tried:

```
  for layer in autoencoder.layers:
  print(layer.get_output_at(0))
```

And the result is:

```
  Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 784), 
  dtype=float32)
  Tensor("dense_1/Relu:0", shape=(?, 32), 
  dtype=float32)
  Tensor("dense_2/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 
  784), dtype=float32)
```

But, what I need are the values at each layer.

Comment: It seems you are using Keras, right? Getting output values only makes sense when you feed your model with some input values. Otherwise, the model would not generate values by itself.

Comment: I just copied the last portion of my code, yes, I fed to the model the mnist dataset.

Comment: Are you sure? I am **not** referring to training the model. Could you please post the code where you feed the MNIST dataset to your model and expect outputs? And further, `get_output_at()` does not give **output values** of a layer. It is just a reference to the **symbolic** output tensor of that layer.